# Services groovy and multiple machines

Tags: ros, catkin, service, rosservice, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've used ROS since the electric version and made several nodes that included services.
Now in groovy (catkin) I've tried to make a node that advertises a service, everything worked fine until I called it from another machine and got a unknow service error message.

So I tried to do the tutorial of creating a simple service(AddTwoInts), and the same thing happend.(ok in same machine does not work if called from another)
But if I run the cpp begginer tutorials already compiled in ROS groovy the service works in the same machine as well as in multiple machines.
I've altered the package.xml and the CMakelist to the same as in the begginer tutorials in ROS repository.

So I'm kind of lost anybody had the same kind of problem?

Thanks,
Francisco Marques

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58110/services-groovy-and-multiple-machines/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The other machine needs to know the service definition as well.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on 2013-03-15**:
I get that. But I have to build the node that advertises/create the service definition in all of the computers that use that service?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-15**:
Only the service and whatever you use for calling. If that's the case something else is wrong.